# How to add a delay between repeat operations in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I am building a page that displays a bunch of pdf documents to the user.  I am currently using the repeat operator from the 'rxjs/operators' library in order to force the refresh of a documents page.

```
My code is below

    import { map, repeat } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
    // Fetch Document type Filter.
    this.firebaseService
      .documentAdminAccessList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(changes => changes.map(c => ({ value: c.payload.val() }))),
        repeat(5)
```

However, what is happening is that sometimes that the link to the documents page is not appearing in time. I fear that the repeat(5) is being executed too fast. How can I add a 500 millisend delay between each repeat operation?

**Update (Jan 14, 2021),** I am still seeing this issue. The documents link on the Menu bar is still delayed; only after the initial nav bar loads.

Below is my code:
Rafi. Could the 'take' be wrong?

```
// Fetch Document type Filter.
    this.firebaseService
      .documentAdminAccessList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(changes => changes.map(c => ({ value: c.payload.val() }))),
        repeatWhen(x=> x.pipe(delay(250), take(5)))
      )
```

[Link to Navigation Menu Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9oQk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **repeatWhen**
> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable with the
> exception of a complete. If the source Observable calls complete, this
> method will emit to the Observable returned from notifier. If that
> Observable calls complete or error, then this method will call
> complete or error on the child subscription. Otherwise this method
> will resubscribe to the source Observable it returns an Observable
> that mirrors the source Observable with the exception of a complete.  ([Rxjs Docs)](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/repeatWhen)

Consider utilizing it combined with `delay` operator so that when the source Observable completes, the Observable returned by the method `repeatWhen` was passed to (which could be the source Observable it was provided with) would get resubscribed repeatedly (with a delay of X ms between retries) resulting in the source Observable getting resubscribed each time it emits (the Observable `repeatWhen` was provided with) as shown below:

```
repeatWhen(x=> x.pipe(delay(5000)))
```

Looking at your question it seems like you wish to limit repeat count, this can easily be achieved by using `take(5)` operator as demonstrated below:

```js
of(SOME_VALUE)
  .pipe(
     repeatWhen(x => x.pipe(delay(500), take(5)))
  )
 .subscribe(x => {
     console.log(x)
 })
```

Comment: Hi Rafi, I ended up putting a .pipe(
        map(changes => changes.map(c => ({ value: c.payload.val() }))),
        repeat(5), delay(250),  but I don't think this works. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the solution suggested above?

Comment: Excellent.  Your suggestion works Rafi :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!. If the answer above fixed your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Comment: Done. Thx. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Rafi.  I am reopening this question, as the issue is occurring again.